# Android - Translating menu tab

Tags: android, translation, multilingual

There is a simple way to translate menu tab's text using values strings.xml?
  Since the menu text is set on java, i don't see a way to do that.

If there isn't, which is the better way to do that?

**SOLVED:**

Method to recover a string: getString(R.string.tela_principal_menu_tab_um);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether your menu is built in XML or Java, you should be able to use strings.xml.  You can access your strings in Java using `getString(R.string.string_name)`.  See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html, and then just follow the instructions for localization: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html for your strings.

Comment: I found that i can use `getString(R.string.anything)` to recover a string inside java. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it helped.  If you would mark this as the correct answer, it would help me, too.  :)

Answer (score 1):

While you cannot do it in strings.xml as easily, I frequently use a menu resource in xml. It works like so:

Create a folder in `res\` named `menu`.

Set up the XML file initially like this

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- menu contents in here... -->
</menu>`
```

Now you can add your menu into the space indicated above. `Groups` can hold multiple `Items`, or you can just hold `Items` in there. Each has its own `id` so you can reference it quickly and easily. Here is a full sample..

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/cmd1" android:title="My 1st Command" android:enabled="true" android:visible="true" />
    <item android:id="@+id/cmd2" android:title="My 2nd Command" android:enabled="true" android:visible="true" />
    <item android:id="@+id/cmd3" android:title="My 3rd Command" android:enabled="true" android:visible="true" />
    <item android:id="@+id/cmd4" android:title="My 4th Command" android:enabled="true" android:visible="true" />
</menu>
```

Now you can simply add it to your code like so:

```
@Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu newMenu)
{//Clear the Current Menu
    newMenu.clear();
// Reinflate the Menu
    final MenuInflater _inflate = getMenuInflater();
    _inflate.inflate(R.menu.app_menu, newMenu);
// Set the ClickListener to This
    final int _numItems = newMenu.size();
    for (int _iItem = 0; _iItem < _numItems; _iItem++)
        newMenu.getItem(_iItem).setOnMenuItemClickListener(this);
// Return as Handled (true)
    return true;
}
```

Finally, you add the onClicks:

```
@Override public boolean onMenuItemClick(final MenuItem onItem)
{//Determine which MenuItem was Clicked
    switch (onItem.getItemId())
    {   case R.id.cmd1:
        //Action code
            break;
        case R.id.cmd2:
        //Action code
            break;
        case R.id.cmd3:
        //Action code
            break;
        case R.id.cmd4:
        //Action code
            break;
    }
// Return as Handled (true)
    return true;
}
```

Hope this helps!

FuzzicalLogic